# Parent of a flex container does not size on Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this simple HTML setup:

```
<a>
  <span class='amount'>XX €</span>
  <span class='text'>
    <span>COIN</span>
    <span>foo</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k5fas9yy/2/

What I want is the floating element to be at the right of the flexbox. Works fine in Chrome, Edge, IE11. But with Firefox, it seems the `a` takes the width of the flex container, which puts the flexbox below the floating element. How can I make it grow to fit everything correctly?

Comment: If you're using flexbox, why not just use it throughout? You have a mix of inline-block, floats and inline elements and flexbox in there I'm pretty sure some of those spans should probably be divs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `display:flex`, use `display:inline-flex`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  color: white;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7.5px 15px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
.amount {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.text {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <span class='amount'>XX €</span>
  <span class='text'>
        <span>COIN</span>
  <span>foo</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

**Tested in FF 41.0.2**